# Dereference pointers from threads

Tags: c

How would I deference my argument to get the integer value in my print statement and also free the pointer inside the function?

This is a simpler version of what I'm running into with a project I'm working on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>


void* my_Func(void *received_intPointer){
    int val = *(int*) received_intPointer;
    printf("value: %d \n", val);
    free(received_intPointer);
    
}
int main(){
    int array[5];
    int *ptr[5];
   
   for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        ptr[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    }
    
    printf("\nEnter 5 numbers:\n");
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        ptr[i] = &array[i];
    }
    pthread_t tid[5];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, my_Func, &ptr[i]);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){    
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: I took the `&` off of `&ptr[i]` and got the correct result.  https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/SubtleAggravatingSoftwareengineer#main.c

Comment: `ptr[i] = &array[i];` assigns address of array+i to element in ptr array, so the reference to malloced memory is lost. It should be `*(ptr[i]) = array[i];`

Comment: "Dereference pointers from threads" has NOTHING to do with "threads" per se: all variables - and all pointer variables - are in the same address space, regardless of thread.

Answer (score 1):

Two bugs here:

- `my_Func` is expecting its argument to be a pointer to the `int` that it should print (where that pointer has been cast to `void *`).  `ptr[i]` is supposed to be that pointer.  But you are passing `&ptr[i]` which is a *pointer* to that pointer.  In other words, your function is really expecting `int *` but you pass it `int **`.  So it should be:

```
        pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, my_Func, ptr[i]);
```

- `ptr[i] = &array[i];` overwrites the *pointer* `ptr[i]` with a pointer to the int `array[i]`.  So `ptr[i]` is no longer the pointer you received from `malloc`.  You have leaked that memory, and what is worse, `my_Func` will attempt to free `&array[i]` which is not malloc'ed.

  I think you wanted to copy the int from `array[i]` into the space you malloced previously, so this line should be `*ptr[i] = array[i];`.